# Need to save the file to a specific folder instead of my drive directory. Is there a way?

Tags: google-apps-script

here's my code

function onOpen() {
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('CreatePDF').addItem('CreatePDF', 'CreatePDF').addToUi()
}

```
function CreatePDF(){

let copyFile = DriveApp.getFileById('1NKX72gRqZ5XFOS8PbNQFN1cqgWNFsA4wt2NlR3qR2XU').makeCopy(),
    copyId = copyFile.getId(),
    copyDoc = DocumentApp.openById(copyId),
    copyBody = copyDoc.getBody()

let activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(),
    numberOfColumns = activeSheet.getLastColumn(),
    activeRowIndex = activeSheet.getActiveRange().getRowIndex(),
    activeRow = activeSheet.getRange(activeRowIndex, 1, 1, numberOfColumns).getDisplayValues(),
    headerRow = activeSheet.getRange(2, 1, 1, numberOfColumns).getValues(),
    columnIndex = 0

for (; columnIndex < headerRow[0].length; columnIndex++){
  copyBody.replaceText('{' + headerRow[0][columnIndex] + '}', activeRow[0][columnIndex])
}
    
copyDoc.saveAndClose()

let newFile = DriveApp.createFile(copyDoc.getAs('application/pdf'))

newFile.setName('PAC -' + activeRow[0][0] + '_' + activeRow[0][4])

copyFile.setTrashed

SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('PAC Completed')

}
```

Comment: In your script, how about modifying from `let newFile = DriveApp.createFile(copyDoc.getAs('application/pdf'))` to `let newFile = DriveApp.getFolderById("###folderId###").createFile(copyDoc.getAs('application/pdf'))` or `let newFile = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("###folderName###").next().createFile(copyDoc.getAs('application/pdf'))`?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.